# Join an existing Google Meet meeting from the home screen with an URL

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, google-meet

This seems to be quite an edge case, as I can find no information on this.

**Context**
We have a regular "coffee chat" meeting in our group, and we use a Google Meet URL for this meeting, always the same, and we meet at known times a day. No need to have a calendar entry for this.

So, on the desktop computer, I can always easily reuse the URL (e.g. such one: https://meet.google.com/abc-defg-hjk) like described [here](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/9303069?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop).

**Problem**
But now I am mostly using my Android Tablet to join, and I wonder how to set up a Home Screen icon/widget/link with that URL.

I can use Google Chrome to paste the URL into, but it will automatically start the Meet app. I have no chance to create a shortcut link first. Also, I have not found yet a way to create a link directly from the home screen.

**Question**
How to create a home screen icon/link/widget that directly opens a given Google Meet URL?

Comment: I haven't tried this, and this might be a bad workaround after all, but what if you disable the Meet app for a while, then paste the URL on Google Chrome?

Comment: On Android 10,even after disabling open links in Hang outs app it  still opens in app. But using Firefox, shortcut opens in web page. @AndrewT our comments crossed. Google seems to hardwire things for their apps

Comment: If nothing else works you can think of using Firefox

Comment: @AndrewT.How to "disable" an app? I can only "Force Stop", which does not help, and uninstall, which I did not try yet.

Comment: @beeshyams Also using Firefox immediately opens the Meet app.

Comment: Marcel not for me on One Plus 7. What @AndrewT was referring to is this probably and which I did before testing on FF. From settings search opening links, disable instant apps (maybe not needed), and in the installed apps locate Hangout, click on it and open supported link set it to don't open on this app

Comment: See this screen recording https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZfolgkZbPiFlTHUOEz8bUPyl14YVHPjpkCX

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that only system apps can be disabled while 3rd-party apps can only be forced-closed from App Info. I seem to be mixing up with [`pm disable` thing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128949)...

Comment: @Marcel if I uninstall hangouts, I can use Chrome shortcut as you wanted but make sure you disabled instant apps preferences as in earlier comment

Comment: I now uninstalled both Hangouts and Meet, and still, when opening the link in either Firefox or Chrome, the Play store immediately opens with the Hangouts Meet app recommending to install. WTF!

Comment: Also, disabling "instant apps", as recommended above, did not help, still the same behaviour.

How hard can one make this!

Comment: In now tried this as a workaround: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/185258/40418 Unfortunately, it now opens the play store first, so requires one additional click. But it's usable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn off the internet on the device and open the meet URL in a browser. Now, the URL will stay in the adress bar, and you can save it to the home screen the usual way.